# How can I create an iOS style PIN/password box with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a html5 input that looks like the iOS enter Pin (on the lock screen).... with 4 input boxes.

How do i achieve this?

[image]

**I tried the following:**

1) Created a normal input box.

2) Removed its borders.

3) Placed the above image as the background of the input box.

4) And added some letter spacing.

Problem is: As i type the first 3 characters, it fits in the boxes:

[image]

But when i type the 4th character, the characters move towards the left and hence it appears as below:

[image]

What can I do to fix this ?

Any other better approach ??

**EDIT:**

Ok based on the below answers, I modified the approach to have 4 input boxes. And on **keyup** event for each input box, I change the **focus** to next input box.

This works well on browser. But does not work on the device (iPhone 5). What is the problem ?

It is a Sencha Touch app packaged using Cordova.

**SOLVED:**

Need to disable `<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />`

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a demo fiddle.

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have? your html and css, a fiddle would be great.

Comment: For complete javascript solution, check- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176432/6719426

Comment: You can solve this using just html and CSS. See my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of images, have 4 input boxes. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JLyn9/2/

```
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="1" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'a')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="a" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'b')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="b" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'c')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="c" />

moveOnMax =function (field, nextFieldID) {
    if (field.value.length == 1) {
        document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
    }
}
```

PS the JS function can be optimized.

**EDIT/WARNING**: This is not a solution to this problem. Please look at the other answers

Comment: thanks. i am using sencha touch to create the input components.. so my code is a bit different. but I got the idea.. and i have implemented in a similar way. thanks for the approach

Comment: @stackErr What if user want to use backspace to delete pin and move to previous field

Comment: This works awfully. You should try something else. I also see the issue @EmptyData points out.

Comment: @EmptyData Hi, I would like to get feedback from you about my solution to this problem, please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/73847672/17948008.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `background-image` for this purpose, use four `input` boxes with their `type` set to password, and than use jQuery to achieve some more user friendliness, if you don't need that functionality of auto focusing to next field you can simply omit the script out and achieve your style..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVnd5/)

```
input[type=password] {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

jQuery (Optional for auto focus functionality)

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length >= 1) {
      var input_flds = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
      input_flds.eq(input_flds.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Would be great to have it so that backspace would go back to the previous input.

Answer (score 4):

No need for jQuery, much cleaner IMO.

HTML

```
<form id="ios">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1"/>
    <input type="password" maxlength="1"/>
    <input type="password" maxlength="1"/>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form#ios input[type=password]{
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/jerryhuangme/e9yhr/

Comment: I've not used jQuery to style elements :) that option is used for auto focus

Comment: @Mr.Alien, ah.  I should have RTFM. Just saw $("input").keyup(function() and was scratching my head. That's a nice snippet of UI design there. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the style clean,
I would suggest you to create 4 `input` boxes.

Write a small script to focus the next input box when user enters character in the current input box.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input[name*=pin]").keyup(function(e) {
  if($(this).val().length == 1) {
    $(this).attr('type', 'password');
    var input_fields = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name*=pin]');
    input_fields.eq(input_fields.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode==8 && e.currentTarget.name !== 'pin01') {
    $(this).attr('type', 'number');
    var input_fields = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name*=pin]');
    input_fields.eq( input_fields.index(this) - 1 ).attr('type', 'number').focus(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" class="form-pin">
  <input type="number" maxlength="1" name="pin01" class="input-pin" pattern="\d*" />
  <input type="number" maxlength="1" name="pin02" class="input-pin" pattern="\d*" />
  <input type="number" maxlength="1" name="pin03" class="input-pin" pattern="\d*" />
  <input type="number" maxlength="1" name="pin04" class="input-pin" pattern="\d*" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" class="display-otp-box" data-key="otp1">
 <input type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" class="display-otp-box" data-key="otp2">
 <input type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" class="display-otp-box" data-key="otp3">
 <input type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" class="display-otp-box" data-key="otp4">


$('.display-otp-box').on('keyup', function (e) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        
  /* for backspace, focus will move to the previous box */ 
  if( key === 8 || key === 46 ){
     $(this).prev('input').focus();
     return;
  }
  $(this).next('input').focus();
 });
```

- type="tel" on the input will make sure the numeric keypad appears when using on the phone
- next input will be focused automatically with the help of tabindex.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen all the answers but none solves the issue when backspace is clicked,

to tackle that here is my solution,

HTML:

```
        <input class="input" type="text" id="input-1" maxlength=1 data-id="1" />
        <input class="input" type="text" id="input-2" maxlength=1 data-id="2" />
        <input class="input" type="text" id="input-3" maxlength=1 data-id="3" />
        <input class="input" type="text" id="input-4" maxlength=1 data-id="4" />
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
const loginInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");

loginInputs.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    const id = +e.target.dataset.id;
    if (e.key === "Backspace") {
      if (id === 1) return;
      const prevEl = document.getElementById(`input-${id - 1}`);
      prevEl.focus();
    } else {
      if (id === 4) return;
      const nextEl = document.getElementById(`input-${id + 1}`);
      nextEl.focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is pretty good.  I created a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/9q83gbn2/

Answer (score 0):

No need for JS.
This solution covers back-spacing, copy/pasting etc, just using `html` and `CSS`.

If the numbers in the input field move towards the right when typing the 4th number, it is likely due to the default behavior of some web browsers that display the characters entered in the input field as asterisks or bullets. This behavior can cause the input text to appear shifted to the right.

To resolve this issue, you can modify the  element to use a fixed-width font. This ensures that each character occupies the same amount of space, preventing the shifting effect. You can apply a CSS style to the input field to achieve this:

`<input type="text" id="pin-input" maxlength="4" style="font-family: monospace;">`

full `html` component:

```
        <div id="pin-container">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <label for="pin-number" class="sr-only">PIN</label>
          <input type="password" name="pin-number" id="pin-number" maxlength="4" style="font-family: monospace;">
        </div>

<style>
  #pin-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  #pin-container div {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: left;
    height: 3em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    width: 3em;
  }
  #pin-number {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    bottom: 1.1em;
    /* font-family: monospace; <-- here or inline html */
    font-size: 1.9em;
    left: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 1.64em;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```