# How to partition input field to appear as separate input fields on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look at the image:

[image]

I want design something like in the image, where a 4 digit one time password (OTP) is to be entered by user. Right now I have achieved this by 4 separate inputs and then combining values in javascript:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="1"  />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" />
```

I am not sure if this is correct approach. I think there must be some styling options by which one input textbox would appear as partitioned one like in the image. Is it possible using bootstrap? How to style one input control to be appeared as partitioned field of inputs?

Comment: It will be helpful for you http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Maybe you can try css "letter-spacing" property to increase spacing in your input field text. Plus you can "tune" the bottem border dash style to fit the spacing you have. The following link will probably help you to adjust the width of dashes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You don't have to keep four separate fields.

First, you should adjust the character spacing, and then adjust the border style of bottom.

```css
#partitioned {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  outline : none;
}
```

```html
<input id="partitioned" type="text" maxlength="4" />
```

--EDIT to fix 5 underlines for 4 character ugliness--

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('partitioned');
obj.addEventListener('keydown', stopCarret); 
obj.addEventListener('keyup', stopCarret); 

function stopCarret() {
    if (obj.value.length > 3){
        setCaretPosition(obj, 3);
    }
}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#partitioned {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

#divInner{
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#divOuter{
  width: 190px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOuter">
    <div id="divInner">
        <input id="partitioned" type="text" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this can be a starting point.

Hope this will help...

Comment: i am facing an issue with the alignment of the character if we does't give max length 4 the after entering few digits the number is goes right side it is not aligning center of the dash of the input field

Comment: yes you are right, and it seems this is the limitation :( and as a side note, there is actually 5 partition line. To this this uglyness, you can place the input field in a div, and that div inside another... the inner div must be sticky and the outer div must hide overflows...

Comment: @UfukOnder can you help me for text length 6?

Comment: And what about the credit card number or date field?

Comment: want to remove the blue rectangle border when clicked? you can add `outline:none` as a css rule to the `#partitioned` styles

Answer (score 52):

I know this question is old. I stumbled upon this when I was trying to achieve the same for my project.

I couldn't find what I needed. So I made one myself with the ideas from here

You can use this with any number of characters and needs no change in javascript as long as all the input fields are inside a `div` with `id="otp"`.

---

*Here is a preview:*

[image]

---

Take a look at the code [here](https://gist.github.com/midhunmonachan/3c2fb506cab7e63ffbbd94080a0d2d80)

```js
function OTPInput() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#otp > *[id]');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.key === "Backspace") {
        inputs[i].value = '';
        if (i !== 0)
          inputs[i - 1].focus();
      } else {
        if (i === inputs.length - 1 && inputs[i].value !== '') {
          return true;
        } else if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
          inputs[i].value = event.key;
          if (i !== inputs.length - 1)
            inputs[i + 1].focus();
          event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) {
          inputs[i].value = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
          if (i !== inputs.length - 1)
            inputs[i + 1].focus();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
OTPInput();
```

```css
@import url('https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css');
.form-control {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center
}

.form-control:focus {
  color: #3F4254;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #884377;
  outline: 0;
}

.form-control.form-control-solid {
  background-color: #F3F6F9;
  border-color: #F3F6F9;
  color: #3F4254;
  transition: color 0.15s ease, background-color 0.15s ease, border-color 0.15s ease, box-shadow 0.15s ease;
}

.form-control.form-control-solid:active,
.form-control.form-control-solid.active,
.form-control.form-control-solid:focus,
.form-control.form-control-solid.focus {
  background-color: #EBEDF3;
  border-color: #EBEDF3;
  color: #3F4254;
  transition: color 0.15s ease, background-color 0.15s ease, border-color 0.15s ease, box-shadow 0.15s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-6 text-center">
  <div id="otp" class="flex justify-center">
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="first" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="second" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="third" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="fourth" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="fifth" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="m-2 text-center form-control form-control-solid rounded focus:border-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline" type="text" id="sixth" maxlength="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mihun Can you explain how to add only numbers in the input fields? . OTP screens need only numbers.

Comment: this is how it should be done.  The rest of the answers are just not in a good way. thanks for the function snippet :D

Comment: I found that when backspacing on the last input field it actually clears the last input as well as the second to last. Easy fix is to just check for last input and handle it differently `if (i == inputs.length - 1)` in the case of a backspace

Comment: Love this solution! Just a thought, how would you handle the user pasting a code? I think from a UX perspective, the majority of people would paste their 2FA code in, or even just click the new "code from message" button on their phone when your input has the `autocomplete="one-time-code"` attribute and they receive their code via SMS

Comment: @S_R pasting isn't an issue as there is an on-paste event you can listen to and just manually set the values. But i do wonder about the autocomplete="one-time-code" and if there is a way to listen to that event or handle it with multiple inputs like here

Comment: As a heads up, using individual inputs could potentially cause confusion for people using screen readers. I think that's why other options are trying to get away with using 1 input with a background image. (A single input is also easier if you want auth to work without JavaScript in your app.) Hard decisions.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me without any extra javascript code.

```css
#partitioned {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

#divInner{
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#divOuter{
  width: 190px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOuter">
  <div id="divInner">
<input id="partitioned" type="text" maxlength="4" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"  onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==4) return false;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working and i need to  know what to chnage to make it a 6 digit input field?

Comment: @MrZid to make it 6 digit input field you have to make the following changes.
1. Change the min-width and width of #partitioned to 305px in CSS
2. Change the width of #divOuter to 290px in CSS
3. and change maxlength = "6" and onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==6) return false;" in HTML

Comment: its accepting alphabets also... should accept only numbers because its an otp

Comment: want to remove the blue rectangle border when clicked? you can add `outline:none` as a css rule to the `#partitioned` styles

Comment: Amazing solution without javascript. And comment of @TanujK for 6-digit otp is also commendable...

Answer (score 13):

Hope this solution helps you. You can remove **onfocus** event from **input** elements if you want.

```html
<body>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type=number] {
          height: 45px;
          width: 45px;
          font-size: 25px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
      }
      input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function getCodeBoxElement(index) {
        return document.getElementById('codeBox' + index);
      }
      function onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
        const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (getCodeBoxElement(index).value.length === 1) {
          if (index !== 4) {
            getCodeBoxElement(index+ 1).focus();
          } else {
            getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();
            // Submit code
            console.log('submit code ');
          }
        }
        if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
          getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
        }
      }
      function onFocusEvent(index) {
        for (item = 1; item < index; item++) {
          const currentElement = getCodeBoxElement(item);
          if (!currentElement.value) {
              currentElement.focus();
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        <input id="codeBox1" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(1, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(1)"/>
        <input id="codeBox2" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(2, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(2)"/>
        <input id="codeBox3" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(3, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(3)"/>
        <input id="codeBox4" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(4, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(4)"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just keep this 4 separate fields approach, and add the same event handler to all of them, which will:

1. Check whether the input is valid (in the character class, you're willing to accept)
2. Check which field you are at, and then move the focus to the next field, or the ok button.

You can even write a little separate JS for that, and re-use it.

Answer (score 3):

Just changed Midhun Monachan's snippet to add copy-paste feature.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   
    function OTPInput() {
        const editor = document.getElementById('first');
        editor.onpaste = pasteOTP;

        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#otp > *[id]');
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            inputs[i].addEventListener('input', function(event) { 
                if(!event.target.value || event.target.value == '' ){
                    if(event.target.previousSibling.previousSibling){
                        event.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.focus();    
                    }
                
                }else{ 
                    if(event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling){
                        event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
                    }
                }               
            });             
        } 
    } 
    OTPInput(); 
});

function pasteOTP(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let elm = event.target;
    let pasteVal = event.clipboardData.getData('text').split("");
    if(pasteVal.length > 0){
        while(elm){
            elm.value = pasteVal.shift();
            elm = elm.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
input {
text-align: center!important;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
            margin: 0.5rem !important;
                overflow: visible;
                word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-Xj2sd25G+JgJYwo0cvlGWXoUekbLg5WvW+VbItCMdXrDoZRWcS/d40ieFHu77vP0dF5PK+cX6TIp+DsPfZomhw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<form id="otpForm" >
              <div class="container height-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  <div class="position-relative">
                      <div class="card p-2 text-center">
                          
                          <div id="otp" class="inputs d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-2"> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="first" maxlength="1" /> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="second" maxlength="1" /> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="third" maxlength="1" /> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="fourth" maxlength="1" /> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="fifth" maxlength="1" /> 
                            <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="sixth" maxlength="1" /> 
                          </div>
                         
                      </div>                    
                  </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below directive if using AngularJS

In your HTML add

```
<div otp-input-directive options="otpInput"></div>
```

In your controller add

```
$scope.otpInput={
        size:6,
        type:"text",
        onDone: function(value){
            console.log(value);
        },
        onChange: function(value){
            console.log(value);
        }
    };
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCHuJT?p=preview/%22Demo%22)

[UI component look and feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfOUP.gif)

https://github.com/amstel91/otp-input-directive

Comment: Can you summarize the relevant parts as part of the answer?

Comment: Nice, can you try to copy and paste into this?

Answer (score 0):

```
If your using input type number, then use below code, It's Working


#otpOuterBlock{
  width: 190px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
#otpInnerBlock{
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#otpVerifyText{
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}


input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}



<div id="otpOuterBlock">
    <div id="otpInnerBlock">
        <input id="otpVerifyText" type="number" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#partitioned {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  outline : none;
}
```

```html
<input id="partitioned" type="text" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#partitioned {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 42px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  outline: none;
}

#divInner {
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#divOuter {
  width: 190px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOuter">
    <div id="divInner">
        <input id="partitioned" type="text" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as the others. You should add an explanatory text stating how your answer differs from others.