# Input field - Restrict to One digit

Tags: css, html

[image: expected UI]

I want to re-create this above shown design using an Input field. However, the user should be able to enter only one numeric digit per box. How can I restrict the user to enter only 1 digit per input box.  Please suggest.

Edit: this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272833/4597) solves most of the problem, but does not restrict the input to digits.

Comment: [0] [1] [9] [5] [3] [5]    This is how I want the result to look like

Comment: Can you please provide your code, what do you have so far, and what ideas do you have. Also please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176432/6719426

Answer (score 25):

Use the maxlength and the pattern to allow only one number

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" />
```

Comment: The only small issue with having the type set as text is that letters and symbols can also be used.

Comment: yes you were right i made a little change, thx for the comment ;D

Comment: Thank you for your help guys..

Comment: Just FYI, maxlength does NOT work on input type number. It's only for strings and other inputs.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `focusout` jquery script to check the value isn't greater than 9.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').focusout(function() {
    var max = $(this).val();
    if (max > 9) {
      $(this).val("9");
      alert("Maximum is 9");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" max="9" Min="0" />
<input type="number" max="9" Min="0" />
<input type="number" max="9" Min="0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the number input type, and use max and min. So this should work:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" step="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
   <input type="number" name="abc" min="0" max="9">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only small issue with having the type set as text is that letters and symbols can also be used.