# How to split input box for otp in angular4 and html?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want split input box for otp. How can I do that in angular 4? is there any npm package?

[image]

Comment: you can check https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask

Comment: There are some packages I've used.. Google for angular iput masks. [angular2-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask) , [ng2-inputmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-inputmask)

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698357/how-to-partition-input-field-to-appear-as-separate-input-fields-on-screen and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxUgt/89/) too.

Comment: Nice one. @FatemeFazli Try to copy and paste on that jsfiddle example