# 6 character only print for input field after remove letter spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I refer for this post [How to partition input field to appear as separate input fields on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698357/how-to-partition-input-field-to-appear-as-separate-input-fields-on-screen). It's working for every browser fine. But ie not working for `position:sticky`. any other option i can use, Below my code.

```css
.otp_form_control {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 67px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cacaca 76%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 79px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 60px;
  width: 510px;
  min-width: 510px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#divInner {
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#divOuter {
  width: 455px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOuter">
  <div id="divInner">
    <input id="otp21" class="otp_form_control" name="otp1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

IE browser only not working... Some one help me

Comment: IE does not support [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility) at all. There is a polyfill you can use though: https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill

Comment: I know guys, I need remove letter spacing issue..

Comment: Please run the code in ie browser, It's not working for properly, I need that solution

Comment: I know, that's why I gave you the solution above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried this, it's not working for me. If you have worked. please add

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried do you have any solution...

Comment: The one I linked to previously works absolutely fine. If you have a specific issue with it I would suggest you start a new question about that - making sure to include how you have incorporated the polyfill in to the page, and any errors you get in the console

Comment: Ok. I will change my format, can you remove duplicate this question.

Comment: No. Please ask a new question