# How to make a OTP-based input design with one input field?

Tags: html, css

I know this question was already asked here: [How to partition input field to appear as separate input fields on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698357/how-to-partition-input-field-to-appear-as-separate-input-fields-on-screen)

But the design there is just underline-based design, I want to achieve this design:

[image]

But I'm not much of a frontend developer and I'm not familiar with using `background-image: linear gradient`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to do some styling and you done with what you want so here is HTML, CSS and jQuery code for user type with max number on one input field.

for input and automatic user move to next input field you need to use jQuery CDN i.e Content Delivery Network

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
```

```js
$('.digit-group').find('input').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('maxlength', 1);
  $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
    var parent = $($(this).parent());

    if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
      var prev = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('previous'));

      if (prev.length) {
        $(prev).select();
      }
    } else if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || e.keyCode === 39) {
      var next = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('next'));

      if (next.length) {
        $(next).select();
      } else {
        if (parent.data('autosubmit')) {
          parent.submit();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');

$BaseBG: #ffffff;

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}

body {
  background-color: $BaseBG;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.digit-group input {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: lighten($BaseBG, 5%);
    border: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    border: 3px solid #293886;
  }

.prompt {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Edge */
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #9c9a9a;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer */
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #9c9a9a;
}

::placeholder {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #9c9a9a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" class="digit-group" data-group-name="digits" data-autosubmit="false" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="digit-1" name="digit-1" data-next="digit-2" placeholder="-" />
  <input type="text" id="digit-2" name="digit-2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" placeholder="-" />
  <input type="text" id="digit-3" name="digit-3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" placeholder="-" />
  <input type="text" id="digit-4" name="digit-4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" placeholder="-" />
  <input type="text" id="digit-5" name="digit-5" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-4" placeholder="-" />
  <input type="text" id="digit-6" name="digit-6" data-previous="digit-5" placeholder="-" />
</form>
```

Here you can play with [My Fiddle Editor](https://jsfiddle.net/uv758a92/2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, as stated on my question, what I'm looking for is to achieve the design using ONE input field.

Comment: I tried this code, but it has a bug, when I type `123456` fast on my keyboard it skips some of the textboxes

Answer (score 2):

It this okay ?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

function OTPInput() {
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#otp > *[id]');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { inputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { if (event.key==="Backspace" ) { inputs[i].value='' ; if (i !==0) inputs[i - 1].focus(); } else { if (i===inputs.length - 1 && inputs[i].value !=='' ) { return true; } else if (event.keyCode> 47 && event.keyCode < 58) { inputs[i].value=event.key; if (i !==inputs.length - 1) inputs[i + 1].focus(); event.preventDefault(); } else if (event.keyCode> 64 && event.keyCode < 91) { inputs[i].value=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); if (i !==inputs.length - 1) inputs[i + 1].focus(); event.preventDefault(); } } }); } } OTPInput(); });
```

```css
.height-100 {
    height: 100vh
}

.card {
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    height: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px #d2dae3;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center
}

.card h6 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px
}

.inputs input {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0
}

.card-2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.card-2 .content {
    margin-top: 50px
}

.card-2 .content a {
    color: red
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 2px solid red
}

.validate {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 140px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container height-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="card p-2 text-center">
         
           
            <div id="otp" class="inputs d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-2"> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="first" maxlength="1" /> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="second" maxlength="1" /> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="third" maxlength="1" /> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="fourth" maxlength="1" /> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="fifth" maxlength="1" /> <input class="m-2 text-center form-control rounded" type="text" id="sixth" maxlength="1" /> </div>
            <div class="mt-4"> <button class="btn btn-danger px-4 validate">Validate</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NO. It ask for ONE input field