# Convert object values ​to a number

Tags: javascript

I implemented the idea of ​​OTP input in react and the result was an object as follows :

```js
{input1: '8', input2: '8', input3: '8', input4: '8'}
```

How to convert this object into a continuous number as follows : 8888

thank you

Comment: You can iterate through the object and append it to a string and parse it as a number.
`Number(Object.values(inputs).join(""));`  should work.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem, generally the OTP input field is a single input with custom styling. ie  [How to partition input field to appear as separate input fields on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698357/how-to-partition-input-field-to-appear-as-separate-input-fields-on-screen) or [How to make a OTP-based input design with one input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691128/how-to-make-a-otp-based-input-design-with-one-input-field) or a library which handles basics (pasting, input length, etc) [react-otp-input](https://github.com/devfolioco/react-otp-input)

Comment: option with reduce: `Object.values(inputs).reduce((a, n) => a + n, '');` **All of these cases rely on the sorting of object keys**, which isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, It is better to make **OTP** input field as a single field. Seems you are using 4 separate input fields.

Anyway, the solution for your problem is, that you need to get Object values and `join` the object values as one string, Then convert it to a `Number`.

> **NOTE:** This solution assumes that the keys `input1`, `input2`, `input3` and `input4` are in the correct order.

```js
const obj = {input1: '8', input2: '8', input3: '8', input4: '8'};
// Join object values and convert it to Number
const numValue = Number(Object.values(obj).join(''));
console.log(numValue);
```

Comment: It's actually 3 steps ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Agree, Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are not certain of the order of the keys then you could use

```js
const data = {
  input2: '2',
  input3: '3',
  input1: '1',
  input4: '4'
};

const sortedKeys = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {
  numeric: true
}))

const code = sortedKeys.map(key => data[key]).join('');

console.log(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the entries will be alphabetically sortable we can do this if sort is needed

```js
const data = { input2: '2', input3: '3', input1: '1', input4: '4' };
const result = Object.values(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort())).join('');
console.log(result);
```

Don't do this, but it is really tempting to use `with` here (worth the mandatory downvotes ;) )

```
with (Object) var result = values(fromEntries(entries(data).sort())).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks precision...
but assuming that

- the property names are prefixed with the letters `input` followed by numbers between 1 and 4,
- -- without omitting a single one --,
- Values are always an Ascii of a number from `0` to `9`
- result should be an integer value (and not a string)

```js
console.log(getVal({input1:'8',input2:'8',input3:'8',input4:'8'})); // 8888
console.log(getVal({input1:'5',input4:'8',input2:'6',input3:'7'})); // 5678

function getVal(obj)
  {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i=1; i<5;i++)
    {
    res += Number(obj[`input${i}`]) * 10**(4-i);
    }
  return res
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an index to dynamically order the object keys correctly:

```js
const data = {
  input2: "2",
  input3: "3",
  input1: "1",
  input4: "4"
};

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce(
  (acc, _, i) => `${acc}${data[`input${i + 1}`]}`,
  ""
);

console.log(result); // 1234
```