# Pin / password input (mask), an alternative to letter-spacing / word-spacing or multiple input?

Tags: html, css, input

For a small, mobile first (web)application, I'm trying to create a pin / password input (mask), something like:

```
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
| 1 | | 2 | | 3 | | 4 |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
```

During the implementation of various solutions, the user experience became either unpredictable or confusing, which I hope I can overcome... The options below list the findings I came across, [**demo: implementation of the three solutions (simplified)**](https://jsfiddle.net/6dtdqew6/)

**Multiple inputs**

- Unable to detect backspace (during keydown / keyup) on mobile; this makes navigating to the previous input field, when backspace is pressed and the field is empty, hard to implement.
- Unable to use the 'double tap shift' functionality on the soft-keyboard;  focusing (by user action / scripting) to the next input gives a 'jumping' keyboard (either way in combination with 'double tap shift' autocapitalize on or off)

**Letter-spacing combined with a background repeating-linear-gradient (both calculated)**

- Letter-spacing is somewhat different implemented than one might expect, characters always end with 'letter-spacing', instead of having space between the characters. This causes a horizontal scroll to occur when the 'end' of the input field has been reached
- Removing a character, shifts the whole string, instead of 'emptying' the removed character

**Word-spacing (appending a space after each character) with a background repeating-linear-gradient (both calculated)**

- Removing a character, shifts the whole string, instead of 'emptying' the removed character

So the question is somewhat twofold; first, I may have missed another solution(?) Second, for the solutions mentioned the findings listed can be can be 'countered'(?)

Comment: Give us some code to work with so we don't do the exact same thing you did only to find out it doesn't work. Would much rather work from something.

Comment: @AmericanSlime, code / demo has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery Hotkeys for your input detection:

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Honestly JQuery and it's modules seem to solve most of your problems.

I think you could also benefit from this answer: [CSS: Create iOS style Pin Password box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114366/css-create-ios-style-pin-password-box)