# How to create a 4 digit input series without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a form **input** in which I want to enter a **four-digit number** (verification code). My problem is that after entering the fourth number, the structure and order of the PIN-code breaks down. Because the text pointer goes to the fifth character while I have defined four characters.

Is there a way to solve this problem with pure CSS? Or at least with pure JavaScript?

```css
.pinBox {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
}

.pinBox:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkZl.png);
}

.pinEntry {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16px 29px;
  font-family: courier, monospaced;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 302px;
  letter-spacing: 55px;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.css"/>

<form role="form" method="POST" action="">
  <div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <div class="pinBox">
        <input class="pinEntry" name="token" type="text" maxlength="4" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

here is a [jsfidde demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8o6shp0a/3/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Create iOS style Pin Password box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114366/css-create-ios-style-pin-password-box)

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the comment. It used several inputs ... my code has only one input so this is not my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of investigating I realized that strangely, by assigning `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element resulted in the input to hop/move contextual X position as soon the 4th value was inserted.

### Solution:

- **Use [CSS `clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) on the `<input>` element!**
- Assign the squared grid as the `background-image` of your parent element (no need to use `::before` pseudo elements!)

```css
.pinBox {
  --width: 296px;
  --height: 74px;
  --spacing: 47px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkZl.png); 
}

.pinEntry {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 21px;
  font-family: courier, monospaced;
  font-size: var(--spacing);
  height: var(--height);
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  clip: rect(0px, calc(var(--width) - 21px), var(--height), 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pinBox">
  <input class="pinEntry" name="token" type=text maxlength=4 autocomplete=off >
</div>
```

One *cons* of the above is that: once **all four values are inputted**, and if the user clicks **after the fourth value** - the caret will not be visible since it's **clipped** (letter-spaced inside the 5th position). It you can live with it - good, but it's a bad UX/UI in my opinion.

Perhaps you can add  to the above some really small JS that does:

- IF the input has 4 values length - **select** all the text-value using `myInput.select()`

Example:

```js
const ELS_pinEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".pinEntry");
const selectAllIfFull = (evt) => {
  const EL_input = evt.currentTarget;
  if (EL_input.value.length >= 4) EL_input.select();
};
ELS_pinEntry.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("focusin", selectAllIfFull);
});
```

```css
.pinBox {
  --width: 296px;
  --height: 74px;
  --spacing: 47px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkZl.png); 
}

.pinEntry {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 21px;
  font-family: courier, monospaced;
  font-size: var(--spacing);
  height: var(--height);
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  clip: rect(0px, calc(var(--width) - 21px), var(--height), 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pinBox">
  <input class="pinEntry" name="token" type=text maxlength=4 autocomplete=off >
</div>
```

Another *cons* I would improve by using the above (and the original) idea is: [**A11Y** (Accessibility)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility).
The many users with bad or challenged sight should be able to see an input `outline` while they tab trough a website. For design reasons the above had  to remove the CSS `outline` on the INPUT element. Which is a no-no.

Currently I have no other **better/simpler** idea but to use **4 different inputs** and join their values into a single hidden one that will ultimately be submitted with the FORM.

Comment: but even with that the curser twinking at the end .

Comment: @scriptydude as I said in my Answer... yes, the **blinking caret** should be a **must have** for UI/UX reasons (for which I provided a hacky JS solution) - but in that case the issue is `letter-spacing` which places the caret too far away inside the clipped area. Sadly we don't have any CSS rule for: `letter-spacing-before`

Comment: thanks. I test it in my project and it works well.  I searched about it for days and did not find anything suitable.

Comment: @user2726957 you're very welcome

Comment: This approach has pretty bad UX for users who type the code wrong. It's probably better to use distinct inputs per digit

Comment: @ZachSaucier I agree with you. The numbers shifting and the caret misposition makes it overall a bad UX/UI. I'll rethink on this one. Four distinct inputs are also a pain to handle (perhaps not the editing of a wrong value, but backspacing values, pasting the PIN, handling maxlength, etc.)

Comment: Those do require extra implementation work, but you can get to a pretty good experience by handling those situations with JS.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Obviously *with JS* ;)